# C++ Avoiding Deleting Memory Twice

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, destructor, memory-management

I've run into a problem while working with the built-in pointers in C++. When my program terminates, my classes destructors are all called. I have a data class, a queue class, and another data class which incorporates uses the queue as follows (mind the rough coding on the fly):

```
class Data {
  int x;
}

class Queue {
  class Node {
    Data* x;
  }
  Node* head;
}

class C1 {
  Queue q;
}

class C1Queue{
  class Node {
    C1* c;
  }
  Node* head;
}
```

I also have another Queue, q2, that does not reside in an object. I load both queues from a file, so I say something along the lines of (assuming cQueue is a C1Queue):

```
Data *d = new Data(0);
q2->pushBack(d);
C1 c = new C1();
cQueue->pushBack(c->pushBack(d));
```

As you can see, I have both a queue (q2) holding pointers to each of the data, as well as an object with a queue holding pointers to the same data as q2 is holding. 
Now, when my program terminates I want all the data to be deallocated. However, when the objects are being deallocated, either q2 is deallocated first, and when the C1 objects are to be deallocated, then they deallocate their queues, which then deletes the same data as q2 just deleted. Or the other case is that the objects are deallocated first (I'm not sure which ordering occurs), and then q2 is deallocated and it runs into already deleted memory.

So the problem is that the memory space is being deleted twice, which is not good. Once memory has been deleted, it is released to other programs to use, so deleting that memory space again will result in a seg fault.

Maybe I am missing something here, but I can't figure out how to do this without having a special type of pointer (I cannot use a special type of pointer).

The only way I can think of is to block the C1 object from deallocating it's queue but deallocating the rest of itself, but I don't know how to do that. If someone could help me with this then I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Note that using `delete` on a null pointer is a safe operation (mostly it does nothing). That's why it is highly encouraged to set null pointers to `NULL` or, better yet, `nullptr` after they are `delete`d.

Comment: This is true, but deleting a memory space that has already been freed will result in a segmentation fault on most compilers (as the memory has been given to whatever manages it)

Comment: Oh god, just wait for the shared_ptr guys to come running in. As for your problem, it's generally a good idea to destroy objects in the opposite order they were created in. This should be possible except for multithreaded code. You also need to decide who owns the objects and who merely uses them

Comment: Calling delete on a null pointer is guaranteed safe by the language.  However it is *not* safe to call delete on a non-null pointer more than once.  (termed a "double free")

Comment: @AndrewB a compiler will not tell you about double deletes. It's good practice to NULL the pointer after its object has been deleted

Comment: Or **MUCH MUCH** better yet, and if you encounter similar problems which do not restrict you not to use them, use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Amendment to my first comment: in *"encouraged to set null pointers"*, I mean *raw* pointers. Gotchaed by the 5-minute edit limit. :)

Comment: If possible, it's generally easiest to copy the data instead of having multiple pointers to the same data. If you can't do that, nearly your own reasonable alternative is to use (and write, if you can't avoid it) a reference counting class so you only delete the data when all references to it are gone. Setting the pointers to NULL will not help here, unless you build one that keeps track of all the pointers to a given object, and NULLs *all* the pointers to an object when any of them is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are (apparently) prevented from using niceties like `std::shared_ptr`, you can try one of the following three remedies:

- Manual refcounting. Enforce that every time a `Data` is pushed onto a queue that its refcount be incremented, and decrement the refcount as a `Queue` is cleaned up. When the refcount hits zero, `delete this` (but make sure you always allocate `Data`s on the heap!)
- Designate an object to "own" the `Data` elements. Only that object can destroy `Data` (you may even enforce this with a private destructor and a friend class). You might need more than one of these. (If you refcount this proxy, this becomes a poor man's `std::shared_ptr`).
- Make your `Data`s copyable, and just do everything with brand new objects. This works if it's a small amount of data that doesn't need to stay in sync (for example, a `Point2D` class holding two integers).

Comment: Thank you so much! The refcounting strategy is the one that worked for me. By the way, a way around being forced to allocate on the heap is to make a flag to specify whether it is dynamically allocated or not, and deleting the object if the flag condition holds. Anyways this saved me a worlds of headache, thanks again!